# Error installing xpdf for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, dependencies

Seeing below error. Any suggestions please?

```
sudo apt install xpdf

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xpdf : Depends: libpoppler90 (>= 0.80.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: `xpdf` is not available for 20.04:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xpdf - You can try to install it from its original web site.